# Data Bind Selected Item property for CoverFlow Control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, coverflow

I am using [Coverflow control in Windows 8 C# XAML App](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Jeff-takes-off-the-cover-of-his-CoverFlow-Control-for-Windows-8--Windows-RT).

I am trying to bind the selected Item property of this control to a property but that is not having any effect. Following is my code that i am using do let me know what is the mistake i am doing?

```
 <controls:CoverFlow
     Height="85"
     Margin="0,40,0,0"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     SpaceBetweenItems="35"
     SelectedItem="{Binding DiarySelectedItem.DiarySmileyId}"
     SpaceBetweenSelectedItemAndItems="40"
     ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource 50ItemTemplate}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding DiarySmileyIdOC}" 
     SelectedItemChanged="CoverFlow_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

```
/// <summary>
///     Sets and gets the DiarySelectedItem property.
///     Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event.
/// </summary>
public DiaryItemDetail DiarySelectedItem
{
    get { return _diarySelectedItem; }

    set
    {
        if (_diarySelectedItem == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _diarySelectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(DiarySelectedItemPropertyName);
    }
}

/// <summary>
///     Gets or sets the Diary Smiley Id Observable Collection.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
///     The Diary Smiley Id Observable Collection.
/// </value>
public ObservableCollection<int> DiarySmileyIdOC
{
    get { return _diarySmileyIdOC; }

    set
    {
        if (_diarySmileyIdOC == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _diarySmileyIdOC = value;

        // Update bindings, no broadcast
        RaisePropertyChanged(DiarySmileyIdOCPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're binding `ObservableCollection<int>` to `ItemsSource`, `SelectedItem` is `int` as well. You've taken this into account by binding to `DiarySelectedItem.DiarySmileyId` instead of directly to `DiarySelecteditem`.

This has a side effect though that you're not actually changing `DiarySelectedItem` but only trying to change the value of its `DiarySmileyId` property. This is probably not what you want for several reasons:

- If `DiarySelectedItem` is `null`, nothing will happen because of a silent `NullReferenceException` when assigning to `DiarySelectedItem.DiarySmileyId`.
- If `DiarySelectedItem` is not `null` and `DiaryItemDetail.DiarySmileyId` has a public setter, the value of `DiarySmileyId` property in the instance assigned to `DiarySelectedItem` will change while the other properties will remain the same.
- If `DiarySelectedItem` is not `null` and `DiaryItemDetail.DiarySmileyId` doesn't have a public setter, nothing will happen since `DiarySmileyId` can't be assigned to.

You should have a separate `DiarySelectedItemId` property to achieve the desired behavior:

```
public DiaryItemDetail DiarySelectedItemId
{
    get { return _diarySelectedItem.DiarySmileyId; }

    set
    {
        if (_diarySelectedItem.DiarySmileyId == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        DiarySelectedItem = GetDairyItemDetail(value); // retrieve instance from repository
        RaisePropertyChanged(DiarySelectedItemIdPropertyName);
    }
}

public DiaryItemDetail DiarySelectedItem
{
    get { return _diarySelectedItem; }

    set
    {
        if (_diarySelectedItem == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _diarySelectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(DiarySelectedItemPropertyName);
        // notification to change the selected item in Coverflow if selected item is changed in code
        RaisePropertyChanged(DiarySelectedItemIdPropertyName);
    }
}
```

How come you're not setting `ObservableCollection<DiaryItemDetail>` to `ItemsSource`, so you could bind `SelectedItem` directly to `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Thanks Damir. Actually I would like to elaborate on the situation. There is listview from which the selected field is set into this Coverflow control. But I don't want to make this selection from Coverflow control set back to listview. Therefore I am directly binding the selected object from listview to the Coverflow control.

Comment: @BalrajSingh I'm not sure, I'm following you. You're saying `DiarySelectedItem` is the selected item in your listview, based on which you are selecting the item in coverflow, but you don't want it to change when you select an item in coverflow? Which property would you then want the selected item in coverflow to be set to?

Comment: Actually this is ADD/ Edit Form whose items are displayed in a form of listview. If user selects an item it is displayed in the Edit Form and user can change the values in the form on clicking save button then the changes are saved and reflected in listview. Hence I want to bind the value of selected item from listview to the edit form but on change of edit form value it should not be directly reflected on the listview. When user click of save button it should be reflected and saved. and I want to achieve this using binding of properties. I hope this might help you to understand.

Comment: @BalrajSingh In this case I suggest you still bind `DiarySelectedItem` to selected item of your listview, but in its setter you copy `DiarySmileyId` to a separate `SelectedDairySmileyId` property. You then bind this `SelectedDiarySmileyId` to selected item of coverflow. This way the changes won't immediatelly propagate to the listview. In the command of your `Save` button you copy back the new value from `SelectedDairySmileyId` to the `DiarySelectedItem` property. `DiaryItemDetail` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the changes to be reflected in the listview.